# Does an instanton couple equally to all flavors?

Tags: quantum-chromodynamics, fermions, instantons, non-perturbative

Do gravitational / electroweak / QCD / ... instantons couple equally to all fermion flavors? For example, do QCD instantons distinguish between the different quark flavors?

Edit, due to comment (thanks!): To be more clear, I would like to know if the 't [Hooft vertex](http://arxiv.org/abs/0711.2640) (and its analogs in other field theories) is the same for all fermion flavors or if there are different parameters in the vertex for every flavor.

Comment: What do you mean by "the" QCD instanton, and what do you mean by it "coupling" to certain flavours? An instanton is just a particular field configuration of the gauge field.

Comment: Thanks, I edited my question and hope it is clearer now.

Comment: It couples equally to all massless flavors.